# Changing Sublime Text 3 Indent patterns

Tags: syntax, settings, sublimetext3, indentation

## Smarty indent

is there any solution for changing ST3 indent patterns?
As far as i can judge it, those two files are responsible for how the indenting behaves.
They are located in the Default Package of ST3

```
Default/Indentation Rules.tmPreferences
Default/Indentation Rules - Comments.tmPreferences
```

**But** i cant find any solution to change them. Even if i go into the Default plugin and change the regex directly in the sublime Package, it doesent seem to change anything.

I tried to make a syntax specific file like this.

```
Packages/'Sytnax'/'Syntax'.tmPreferences

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Globals</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>text.html.smarty</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            // rules go here
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to change?